# How to successfully do in app purchases with Qonversion or IAP HUB on React Native?

Tags: android, react-native, in-app-purchase

I have a big struggle implementing IAP.

I receive the following error from Qonversion when trying to purchase after having initialized the SDK in application:
`[Error: Failure to retrieve SkuDetails for the in-app product ID]`

When trying with IAP-HUB, I get the following error:
`GooglePlay did not return the product 'monthly', the product has been filtered, if the sku is valid your GooglePlay account or sandbox environment is probably not configured properly (https://iaphub.com/docs/set-up-android/configure-sandbox-testing)`

I followed the mentionned tutorial without success. I'm surely missing a point but cannot find where.

The products exists on Google Play **and are active**. I'm clueless and I've been trying to finalize this since few days.

I'm testing on **real device** and I have a bundle **uploaded in closed track** and **approved by Google**. But that bundle does not have the `BILLING` permission so I uploaded a new one, maybe it will solve my issue ?

EDIT:
The issue came from an applicationIdSuffix in debug buildType and thus, Qonversion and IAP were unable to find the products.

Comment: https://github.com/qonversion/react-native-sdk/issues/25

Answer (score 3):

The issue came from an applicationIdSuffix in debug buildType.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so for Android to get the subscription/products you must have to release your app on **Open Testing / Closed Testing / Internal Testing**. once you are able to see your app on the play store as a beta available for testing then you are able to get the subscription or products in the array. Hope this will be helpful for you.

Comment: I had released the app as mentionned in the documentation of IAP and Qonversion. The issue came from an applicationIdSuffix in debug buildType. My bad